# How to stop org-mode writing its own link format into LaTeX expressions?

Tags: export, latex, org-mode

If you write something like

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{sallenkey.png}
\caption{
Generic Sallen-Key filter topology. Retrieved from \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sallen-Key_Generic_Circuit.svg}}
\end{figure}
```

the `\url{}` in the caption will be a proper link, but it will look like

> [[https://en.wikipedia.
>   org/wiki/File:Sallen-Key_Generic_Circuit.svg][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:
>   Sallen-Key_Generic_Circuit.svg]]

despite being typeset in LaTeX. How do I prevent org-mode from sticking its nose in this section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that wrapping the statement in `#+BEGIN_LATEX` and `#+END_LATEX` blocks does the trick.